# Trouble using nested routes in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to use nested routes in my React app. I have the following `MainSwitch`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from '../Home/Home';
import Dashboard from '../Dashboard/Dashboard';
const MainSwitch = () => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/' component={Home}></Route>
            <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard}></Route>
        </Switch>
    );
}

export default MainSwitch;
```

This wraps around the app:

```
import React from 'react';
import MainSwitch from './components/MainSwitch/MainSwitch';

import './css/Colors.css';
import './css/App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MainSwitch />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now in the `Home` component I have the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import HomeSwitch from '../HomeSwitch/HomeSwitch';
import NavbarDefault from '../NavbarDefault/NavbarDefault';

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <NavbarDefault />
            <HomeSwitch />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

The second switch `HomeSwitch` is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Landing from '../Landing/Landing';
import Login from '../Login/Login';
import Signup from '../Signup/Signup';
import Pricing from '../Pricing/Pricing';
import NotFound from '../NotFound/NotFound';

const HomeSwitch = () => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Landing}></Route>
            <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}></Route>
            <Route exat path='/signup' component={Signup}></Route>
            <Route exact path='/pricing' component={Pricing}></Route>

            <Route exact path="*"><NotFound /></Route>
        </Switch>
    );
}

export default HomeSwitch;
```

The reason I use two routers is because pages from `Home` and `Dashboard` will have different navigation bars etc.

If I navigate to any of the links in `Home` there are no issues. But if I try to navigate to `/dashboard` I get the `NotFound` page for the `404` error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's the URL when you navigate to the dashboard?

Comment: `http://localhost:3000/dashboard`

Comment: Similar URLs work e.g. `http://localhost:3000/login`

Comment: It's because this `<Route path='/' component={Home}></Route>` also satisfies `http://localhost:3000/dashboard` and once it goes inside none of the routes match `/dashboard`.

Comment: React Router isn't going to come "back up" once it's matched / in the main switch, and /login isn't defined in the home switch so you get NotFound.

Comment: I'm trying to match `dashboard` not `login`

Comment: But I get what you mean because I have a router defined for `/` and sub routes inside that then it will only try to link from the bottom of the tree right?

Comment: @Kex - Can you try what I suggested in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can just switch the order of the routes:

```
const MainSwitch = () => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard}></Route>
            <Route path='/' component={Home}></Route>
        </Switch>
    );
}
```

because this way when you try to go to `/dashboard` it'll first go through `<Route path='/dashboard'`. And since these are in a `Switch`, this path `<Route path='/'` only matches when the path doesn't start with `/dashboard`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<Route exat path='/signup' component={Signup}></Route>` by `<Route exact path='/signup' component={Signup}></Route>`

Pay attention to the **exact** word instead of **exat**.
I had a routeing problem here because of the same mistake.